# Verification of proof that a point of symmetry is mode (Casella-Berger 2.27)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mode, symmetry

I was solving the following problem 2.27 from Statistical Inference by Casella-Berger.

> **2.27** Let $f(x)$ be a pdf, and let $a$ be a number such that if $a\geq x\geq y$, then $f(a)\geq f(x) \geq f(y)$, and if $a \leq x\leq
>  y$, then $f(a) \geq f(x) \geq f(y)$. Such a pdf is called *unimodal*
> with a *mode* equal to $a$.
>
> (c) Show that if $f(x)$ is symmetric($\exists a$ s.t.
> $\forall\epsilon>0$, $f(a-\epsilon)=f(a+\epsilon$)) and unimodal, then
> the point of symmetry is a mode.

**My proof**
Let $a$ be a point of symmetry. Suppose $a$ is not a mode. Then, either one of them is true.

(1) There exist $x,y$ such that $a\geq x\geq y$ and ($f(a)<f(x)$ or $f(x)<f(y)$)

(2)There exist $x,y$ such that $a\leq x\leq y$ and ($f(a)<f(x)$ or $f(x)<f(y)$)

If (1) is true, then by symmetry, there exists $a \leq x'\leq y'$ such that ($f(a)<f(x')$ or $f(x')<f(y')$) is true, meaning (2) is true. similarly, if (2) is true, then (1) is true. So without loss of generality, we can assume (1) is true.

Now, since $f$ is unimodal, there is a mode $b$($\neq a$).
Suppose $a<b$.

Then, if $f(a)<f(x)$ is true, we have a counterexample to the fact that $b$ is a mode since $b \geq a \geq x$ but $f(a)<f(x)$. Similarly if $f(x)<f(y)$ is true, then $b\geq x\geq y$ but $f(x)<f(y)$. Thus, either way, we have a contradiction.

The case $b<a$ can be handled similarly by using (2). Therefore, $a$ is a mode.

---

One concern with my proof is that the solution in the [solution manual](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/%7Ezhu/ams570/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf)(p23)) considers the case when a mode is not unique(such as uniform distribution). I am not sure if my proof handles them.

Comment: There is a much simpler argument: show that (1) if $b$ is a mode of a symmetric distribution centered at $a,$  then $2a-b$ is also a mode (this is immediate); and (2) if $b$ and $c$ are modes of a unimodal distribution, then $(b+c)/2$ is a mode. (If not, this implies at least one of $b$ and $c$ is not a mode.)  These two immediately imply 2.27(c).

Comment: @whuber I think understood your proof. I proved (2) by proving that $f$ would be constant on $[b.c]$ if $b,c$ are both modes. By the way, do you mean that my proof in the question is unreadable and beyond repair?

Comment: Not at all--but its logic is sufficiently convoluted that it could benefit from some simplification.  My hope was (and is) that in simplifying it you could establish whether or not it is fully general (and if not, how to make it so).  I also thought it might be helpful to isolate the roles of the two assumptions (symmetry and unimodality) in the argument, to make it a little more insightful.